# Why am I getting error 8101 when writing a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the table called Sales

```
CREATE TABLE Sales
(
    SaleID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY 
    ,DateOfTransaction dateTime  NOT NULL
    ,QuantitySold int NOT NULL
    ,PaymentMethod nvarchar(40) NOT NULL
    ,EquipmentID int FOREIGN KEY  REFERENCES Equipments(EquipmentID)
    ,CustomerID int  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID)
    ,SalespersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Salespersons(SalespersonID)
);
```

I am writing a stored procedure in which I want to insert the data. This is my code so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sproc_PurchaseAdd
    @SaleID INT OUTPUT 
    ,@DateOfTransaction dateTime
    ,@QuantitySold int
    ,@PaymentMethod nvarchar(40)
    ,@EquipmentId int
    ,@CustomerID int
    ,@SalesPersonId int
AS 
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Sales ON

    INSERT INTO Sales 
    VALUES (@DateOfTransaction, @QuantitySold, @PaymentMethod, @EquipmentId, @CustomerID, @SalesPersonId)

    SET @SaleID = @@IDENTITY 
END
GO
```

But I am getting an error:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sproc_PurchaseAdd, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 75]
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Sales' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Is there any specific thing I am missing? Please help me out

Comment: Please dont spam tag various RDBMS. This does not look like MySQL problem. Remove the tag.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 0):

SaleID is IDENTITY so it wll auto increment,

you don't need this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Sales ON
```

This is ok:

```
INSERT INTO Sales VALUES (@DateOfTransaction,@QuantitySold,@PaymentMethod,@EquipmentId,@CustomerID,@SalesPersonId)
```

If this will not work, try to specify columns:

```
INSERT INTO Sales (DateOfTransaction,QuantitySold,PaymentMethod,EquipmentID,CustomerID,SalespersonID) VALUES (@DateOfTransaction,@QuantitySold,@PaymentMethod,@EquipmentId,@CustomerID,@SalesPersonId)
```

Also try to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead @@IDENTITY

Comment: It is recommend to **always** explicitly define the columns that you want to insert into

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants anyway. Looks like they want the value of the new ID, not to insert it.

Comment: I think that he is getting error trying to insert the record, anyway i've also specified that the best way to get the id is SCOPE_IDENTITY()